# Parallel R code slower inside a function than outside

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing

I have some parallel R code that I want to put inside a function, but the code runs far more slowly when inside a function rather than outside the function.

The code takes a matrix of coordinates and convertes them to `sf` objects. The demo code below runs the same process 2 times.

- Simple Code
- Same code but within a fucntion

Example Code:

```
# Packages
library(parallel)
library(sf)
library(pbapply)

# Sample Data
mat = matrix(runif(1e6,max = 1e5), ncol = 2)
seqs = 1:(nrow(mat)-1)
ncores = 6 # Change as needed

start1 = Sys.time()
# Code not running in a function #########
cl = parallel::makeCluster(ncores)
parallel::clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist=c("mat"), envir = environment())
geoms = pbapply::pblapply(seqs, function(y){sf::st_linestring(mat[c(y,y+1),c(1,2)])}, cl = cl)
parallel::stopCluster(cl)

end1 = Sys.time()

# Same code in a function ###########
func = function(mat, seqs, ncores){
  cl = parallel::makeCluster(ncores)
  parallel::clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist=c("mat"), envir = environment())
  geoms = pbapply::pblapply(seqs, function(y){sf::st_linestring(mat[c(y,y+1),c(1,2)])}, cl = cl)
  parallel::stopCluster(cl)
  return(geoms)
}

start2 = Sys.time()
res = func(mat, seqs, ncores)
end2 = Sys.time()


# Compare Results 
difftime(end1, start1, units = "s")
difftime(end2, start2, units = "s")
```

When the times are compared there is a significant slowdown for code within a function

```
difftime(end1, start1, units = "s")
Time difference of 41.98823 secs
difftime(end2, start2, units = "s")
Time difference of 114.983 secs
```

Comment: If you question is why the delay, then the reason is most likely due to R making a copy of your matrix and passing the copy to the function.  At a million elements this a sizable object to copy.  Handling memory is not R's strength, this it is why growing objects inside loops is a very bad practice.

Comment: Valid point, but it is something more than that, if you run the code you see the `geoms = pbapply::pblapply(seqs, function(y){sf::st_linestring(mat[c(y,y+1),c(1,2)])}, cl = cl)` line is the one running slowly, by that line of code the copying should already have occured